# Symbol not found error in wildcard

Tags: java, wildcard

This is the source code for my program.. On **line 22, in the function sameValue(Gen  ob)**, there is an error which says that it cannot find symbol 'ob'. I am not getting as to, why?

```
class Gen1<T extends Number>
{
    T o;

    Gen1(T o)
    {
        this.o = o;
    }

    String getType()
    {
        return o.getClass().getName();
    }

    double getValue()
    {
        return o.doubleValue();
    }

    boolean sameValue(Gen1 <?> ob)
    {
      double x = ob.doubleValue();
        if (getValue() == x)
            return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
}

class Gen1Example{

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {
        Gen1<Integer> o1 =new Gen1<Integer>(120);
        System.out.println(o1.getType());
        Gen1<Double> o2 =new Gen1<Double>(120.0);
        System.out.println(o2.getType());
        //Gen1<String> o2 =new Gen1<String>("This is a test");
        //System.out.println(o2.getType());
        System.out.println(o1.getValue());
        System.out.println(o2.getValue());
        System.out.println(o1.sameValue(o2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `Gen1` class doesn't have a `doubleValue` method.

Answer (score 1):

You misread the error message. It says

```
Gen1Example.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
      double x = ob.doubleValue();
                   ^
  symbol:   method doubleValue()
  location: variable ob of type Gen1<?>
1 error
```

It complains that in `ob` of type `Gen1<?>` there is no method `doubleValue`.
You probably meant `ob.getValue()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just because `T` extends the `Number` class doesn't mean that `Gen1` does.  You probably wanted something like `ob.getValue()` (or `ob.o.doubleValue()` but this exposes details of implementation) instead.